# How to exit web view to the last fragment?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-webview, back-button

I am trying to exit a web view called on the click of a fragment's element.
Here's my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private WebView webView;
    private CustomPagerAdapter customPagerAdapter;
    private ViewPager2 viewPager;
    TabLayout tabLayout;
    static MainActivity activity;
    static MainActivity activity;

    public static MainActivity getInstance(){
        return activity;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        activity = this;
        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);

        viewPager = (ViewPager2) findViewById(R.id.pager_main);
        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout_main);

        setPagerAdapter();
        customPagerAdapter.addFragment(new GoogleFragment());
        customPagerAdapter.addFragment(new YouTubeFragment());

        new TabLayoutMediator(tabLayout, viewPager,
                (tab, position) -> {
                    if (position == 0) {
                        tab.setText("Google");
                    } else if (position == 1) {
                        tab.setText("YouTube");
                    }
                }
        ).attach();
    }

    private void setPagerAdapter(){
        customPagerAdapter = new CustomPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), getLifecycle());
        viewPager.setAdapter(customPagerAdapter);
    }

    public void setWebView(String url) {
        setContentView(R.layout.web_view);
        webView = (WebView) getInstance().findViewById(R.id.webView);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.loadUrl(url);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){

            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url){
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return false;
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (webView.canGoBack()) {
            webView.goBack();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
            finish();
        }
    }
}
```

On pressing back button, instead of exiting the web view, the app exits itself. The webView.goBack() works fine. But clicking back button from the *main url*, exits the app.
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: what you want to perform when back gets pressed on main url. If your current activity is the last activity in the stack then defintely it will exit the app. This seems expected behaviour

Comment: I don't want to exit the app, rather exit to the GoogleFragment() which is a recycler view. It is on the click of fragment's item that web view is created. So, I want to exit back to that fragment containing the recycler view.

Comment: then remove finish(). just keep super.onBackPressed() in else part

Comment: Already, tried that. It still exits the app.